# Hangfire logging to Application Insights from job enqueued from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

When I enqueue a job from a controller with Hangfire, telemetry is not correlated in Application Insights:

```
public IActionResult Foo()
{
    _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<IFooService>(x => x.StartJob());
    
    return StatusCode((int) HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

For comparison, logs from this controller will have the same `operationId`:

```
public IActionResult Hello()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Hello.");
    _logger.LogInformation("Hello 2.");
    return Ok();
}
```

Also, logs from a hosted service (non-HTTP workloads) will be correlated when manually creating an operation:

```
public class MyHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    public MyHostedService(ILogger<MyHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using var operationHolder = _telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("MyHostedService");

        _logger.LogInformation("Running.");

        ...
    }
}
```

How can make logs to Application Insights have the same `operationId` when a job is enqueued from a controller?

Answer (score 1):

We do it something like this

- get the current ActivityId,
- pass as a parameter to the background job,
- within the job, split that parameter into operationId and parentId,
- then pass it to the TelemetryClient.StartOperation() method.

I don't profess to understand how all this should really hang together, but this seems to achieve something :)

Calling the background job:

```
    // Get the current ApplicationInsights Id, if any. 
    var activityId = System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current?.Id;

    _backgroundJobClient.Schedule<MyJobDefinition>(x =>
            x.DoSomething(otherParams, activityId), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Executing the job:

```
    [AutomaticRetry(OnAttemptsExceeded = AttemptsExceededAction.Delete, Attempts = 10)]
    public async Task DoSomething(string otherParams, string activityId)
    {
        var (operationId, parentId) = SplitCorrelationIdIntoOperationIdAndParentId(activityId);

        // Starting this new operation will initialise System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.
        using (var operation = _telemetryClient.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("MyJobDefinition.DoSomething", operationId, parentId))
        {
            try
            {
                // ... 
                // [ do all the real work here ] 
                // ... 

                operation.Telemetry.Success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                operation.Telemetry.Success = false;

                throw;
            }

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Given an activity id in format like "00-34114526f1cb134bbddd0f256e8bc3f0-972b3bd78c345a46-00",
    /// returns the operationId (first return value) and parentId (second return value).
    /// Refer also to code at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking
    /// although the values we get from System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.Id don't have '.' in them.
    /// All this distributed correlation probably makes sense to someone, but not me. 
    /// See also some useful stuff with id parsing in StartOperation<T> at 
    /// https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/405fd6a9916956f2233520c8ab66110a1f9dcfbc/BASE/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/TelemetryClientExtensions.cs
    /// but I haven't followed that method. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="activityId"></param>
    /// <returns>(operationId, parentId)</returns>
    private static (string, string) SplitCorrelationIdIntoOperationIdAndParentId(string activityId)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(activityId))
            return (null, null);

        var splits = activityId.Split('-');

        // This is what should happen
        if (splits.Length >= 3)
            return (splits[1], splits[2]);

        // Must be in a weird format. Try to return something useful. 
        if (splits.Length == 2)
            return (splits[0], splits[1]);

        return (activityId, null);
    }
```